# xsi:schemaLocation in request xml causing handleJAXBException while umarshalling xml to object with cxf + jax-rs

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, xml-namespaces, xsi

```
cxf version - 2.2.3
spring version - 2.5.5

input xml -

<OTA_HotelAvailRQ EchoToken="ABC123" TimeStamp="2012-01-01T19:00:00" PrimaryLangID="en-us"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 ../Schemas/OTA_HotelAvailRQ.xsd" 
        Version="6.000" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" 
        xmlxsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    .<br>
    . . <br>
    . . .<br>
    . .<br>
    .<br>
</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
```

Observation - when the `xsi:schemaLocation` is removed, the unmarshalling happens seamlessly; however don't have an option removing the `xsi:schemaLocation`

The error trace is -

```
Nov 5, 2012 2:26:50 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider handleJAXBException
WARNING: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "OTA_HotelAvailRQ" is not bound.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:514)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.unmarshalFromInputStream(JAXBElementProvider.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.doUnmarshal(JAXBElementProvider.java:176)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.readFrom(JAXBElementProvider.java:150)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:861)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:459)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:452)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doPost(AbstractCXFServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.service(AbstractCXFServlet.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "OTA_HotelAvailRQ" is not bound.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:334)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
    ... 32 more

Nov 5, 2012 2:26:50 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "OTA_HotelAvailRQ" is not bound.
```

The line xsi:schemaLocation="opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 ../Schemas/OTA_HotelAvailRQ.xsd" is resulting in the unmarshalling expection. Is there a way to ignore or bypass this xsi:schemaLocation?

Comment: what is your question, it is not clear.

Comment: the line xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 ../Schemas/OTA_HotelAvailRQ.xsd" is resulting in the unmarshalling expection. Is there a way to ignore or bypass this xsi:schemaLocation?

Comment: i don't have an answer but you could put at the end of your question to make it clearer for anyone else trying to read.

Answer (score 2):

The line

xmlxsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

is wrong.  That likely should be  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  to define the xsi prefix properly.